# replacing NA values

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a variable that has three values, NA, Yes, MayBe.

When I use levels and class function on that variable I get theses values

```
          > levels(Data1$Case)
          "Yes"                 "May Be"

          > class(Data1$Case)
          "factor"
```

I am trying to replace the NA values with No so I use this code

```
     Data1$Col1[is.na(Data1$Col1)]= "No"
```

I am getting an error,

```
       In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(Data1$Col1), value = c(NA,  :
       invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I wrote an ifelse statement to replace the NA,

```
      Data1$Col1=ifelse(is.na(Data1$Col1_ == 'TRUE'), "No",Data1$Col1)
```

and this works but I am looking for some efficient ways to do replace the NAs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `addNA()` and the `levels<-` replacement function.

```
x <- factor(c(NA, "Yes", "Maybe"))
# [1] <NA>  Yes   Maybe
# Levels: Maybe Yes

## If present, add NA to the factor levels
addNA(x)
# [1] <NA>  Yes   Maybe
# Levels: Maybe Yes <NA>
y <- addNA(x)

## replace the NA level with 'No'
levels(y)[is.na(levels(y))] <- "No"
y
# [1] No    Yes   Maybe
# Levels: Maybe Yes No
```

Comment: never knew about that one

Comment: Nice one! Alternatively, you can add the value to `levels(y)` before trying to change it in the vector.