# Referencing factor levels created by addNA

Tags: r

If I have a factor array with `NA` values it can be convenient to
replaced the missing values with an additional level and the `addNA`
function makes this easy.

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", NA))

x

## [1] a    b    <NA>
## Levels: a b

is.na(x)

## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

x2 <- addNA(x)

x2

## [1] a    b    <NA>
## Levels: a b <NA>
```

But how can this level be referenced? Calling `is.na` or the usual
methods I would use to filter don't work.

```
is.na(x2)

## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

x2 == 'NA'

## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

x2 == '<NA>'

## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon this is about as cleanly as I can do it:

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "b", NA, "a", NA))
x2 <- addNA(x)
x2
#[1] a    b    b    <NA> a    <NA>
#Levels: a b <NA>

is.na(levels(x2))[x2]
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update** (2016-10-04): Not long after asking this question the [forcats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/index.html) package was released. It contains the function `fct_explicit_na` which easily solves this problem.

```
library(forcats)
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "b", NA, "a", NA))
x2 <- fct_explicit_na(x)
x2

## [1] a         b         b         (Missing) a         (Missing)
## Levels: a b (Missing)

x2 == '(Missing)'

## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

In addition to the posted answer I've found that using `droplevels` also works.

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "b", NA, "a", NA))
x2 <- addNA(x)
x2

## [1] a    b    b    <NA> a    <NA>
## Levels: a b <NA>

is.na(droplevels(x2))

## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Another option (as per [this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572479/868622)) is to replace the
`<NA>` level with something else.

```
levels(x2)[is.na(levels(x2))] <- "isNA"

x2

## [1] a    b    b    isNA a    isNA
## Levels: a b isNA
```

Comment: At true. By my reading of the method it seems like `droplevels.factor` is just a call to `factor`.